# How to search cell in UITableView from multiple array in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Actually am getting datas from **JSON** webservice. I need to search data from `UITableView` cells using `uisearchdisplaycontroller`.

I have passed data into cells successfully using `NSMutablArray` with multiple array. But now i need to search data from that.

My array:

```
[
 { 
   "name": "jhon", 
   "city": "chennai",
 }
 { 
   "name": "Micle", 
   "city": "Newyork",
 }
 { 
   "name": "Micle", 
   "city": "Washigton",
 }
]
```

My custom cells in UITableView:

```
cell.P_name.text = [details objectForKey:@"name"];
cell.P_city.text = [details objectForKey:@"city"];
```

In Search i tried :

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
   //-- Help to customize operations
    searchResults = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:mainArray];
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", searchText];
    searchResults = [details filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
   [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Can anybody help to resolve my issue.

Comment: What have you tried to filter the source array (you are not trying to filter cells or interrogate cells)? `NSPredicate`?

Comment: @Wain : Now am added tried code in NSPredicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have 2 arrays:

1. Your main store of data from your JSON (`mainDataList`)
2. Your data source array used to populate your table view(s) (`dataSourceList`)

Initially:

```
self.dataSourceList = self.mainDataList;
```

because you are displaying all of the data in your table view. When any search is cancelled you also go back to this state (then reload).

When searching however, you need to filter the contents of the `dataSourceList` and reload the table:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[cd] %@", searchText];

    self.dataSourceList = [self.mainDataList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

**NOTE:** the above predicate only searches the `name` in your dictionaries...

Now, all of your table view methods only use `self.dataSourceList`, and you modify its contents based on your state. You code is clean and simple. Smile :-)

Answer (score 0):

I just put my logic take one more mutable array in **.h** file name is **_temArray**

And add your **_mainArray** *(populated on tableView)* to your **_temArray** such like,

```
[_temArray addObjectsFromArray:_mainArray];
```

In Search method use `NSPredicate`:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
   //-- Help to customize operations

    if([searchText length] > 0)
    {
        NSMutableArray *fileterMainArray = (NSMutableArray *)_temArray
        NSPredicate *predicatePeople = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", searchText]; // here if you want to search by city then change "name" to "city" at pattern.
        NSArray *filteredArray = [fileterMainArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicatePeople];
        [_mainArray addObjectsFromArray:filteredArray];
    }
    else
        [_mainArray addObjectsFromArray:_temArray];

   [self.tblView reloadData]; // don't forget to reload Table data.
}
```